# Profinite groups and extension of a monomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, profinite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $G^\vee$ be its profinite completion. Suppose we have an injective homomorphism $\varphi: G \rightarrow H$ where $H$ is a profinite group. By the universal property of profinite completion, $\varphi$ induces a continuous map $\varphi^\vee: G^\vee \rightarrow H.$
My question is:
**When is $\varphi$ a monomorphism?**

Answer (score 1):

The profinite completion of any profinite topological group is just itself: the identity map $G\to G$ satisfies the universal property of the profinite completion.  So $G=G^\vee$ and $\varphi^\vee=\varphi$, so $\varphi^\vee$ is injective if $\varphi$ is injective.

Comment: Just to say it explicitly for the OP: finite groups are profinite when you give them the discrete topology.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey:
Thank you for your answer. I made the mistake of writing that $G$is finite, I want $G$ to be any group. What I suspect in this situation, is that $\varphi^\vee$ is injective iff, when we view $G$ as a subset of $H,$ the profinite topology of $G$ is induced from that of $H.$